# Textfields not tracking text

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, material-ui

I have a forum setup using react-redux and material ui. All of the text fields seem to not track  the change of state this is suppose to track..

So when a user attempts to type in the text field nothing happens.

```
onChange={e =>
              onTextFieldChange("workoutCompleted", e.target.value)
            }
```

here is the rest of the forum code im sure its a real simple fix here.

```
import React from "react"
import { connect } from "react-redux"
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField"
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button"
import CustomSnackBar from "../Components/customSnackBar"
import { withStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles"
import { NEW_WORKOUT_FORM_UPDATED } from "../constants"
import { createNewWorkout } from "../action-creators/events"

const styles = theme => ({
  input: {
    width: "50%",
    marginLeft: 16,
    marginTop: 16,
    marginBottom: 10,
    color: "red"
  },
  button: {
    color: "secondary"
  }
})

class NewWorkout extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    console.log("componentDidMount!!!")
  }

  render() {
    console.log("RENDER!!!")
    const { workout, duration, eventDateTime } = this.props.event
    const {
      isError,
      isSaving,
      errorMsg,
      classes,
      onTextFieldChange,
      createWorkout,
      history
    } = this.props

    return (
      <div style={{ paddingTop: 56 }}>
        <form autoComplete="off" onSubmit={createWorkout(history)}>
          <TextField
            label="Workout"
            value={workout}
            onChange={e =>
              onTextFieldChange("workoutCompleted", e.target.value)
            }
            margin="normal"
            required
            className={classes.input}
          />
          <TextField
            label="Duration"
            value={duration}
            onChange={e => onTextFieldChange("Duration", e.target.value)}
            margin="normal"
            required
            className={classes.input}
            multiline
          />

          <TextField
            label="Date"
            value={eventDateTime}
            clickable="false"
            margin="normal"
            required
            className={classes.input}
          />

          <div style={{ paddingTop: 50 }}>
            <Button
              className={classes.button}
              color="red400"
              variant="contained"
              type="submit"
              aria-label="add"
            >
              SUBMIT
            </Button>
          </div>
        </form>
        {isError && <CustomSnackBar message={errorMsg} snackType="error" />}
        {isSaving && <CustomSnackBar message="Saving..." snackType="info" />}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  console.log("What is state?", state)

  return {
    event: state.newWorkout.data,
    isError: state.newWorkout.isError,
    isSaving: state.newWorkout.isSaving,
    errorMsg: state.newWorkout.errorMsg
  }
}

const mapActionsToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    onTextFieldChange: (key, value) => {
      dispatch({ type: NEW_WORKOUT_FORM_UPDATED, payload: { [key]: value } })
    },
    createWorkout: history => e => {
      e.preventDefault()
      dispatch(createNewWorkout(history))
    }
  }
}

const connector = connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapActionsToProps
)

export default connector(withStyles(styles)(NewWorkout))
```

Comment: you are changing "workoutCompleted" but then checking the property inside event "workout"... anyway IMO use state for that, and send to redux when submit the form

Answer (score 0):

```
onChange={e =>
              onTextFieldChange("workoutCompleted", e.target.value)
            }
```

should be

```
onChange= e => {
              onTextFieldChange("workoutCompleted", e.target.value)
            }
```

no?

Comment: no @dgeare {} coming off of the prop represent javascript that needs to be executed .

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help @UXDart

> you are changing "workoutCompleted" but then checking the property
>   inside event "workout"... anyway IMO use state for that, and send to
>   redux when submit the form